# Launch specific version of application with CreateObject("***.Application")

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net windows forms application that is used as an operator interface on our machines.
It launches a piece of measurement software called PC DMIS by

```
CreateObject("PCDLRN.Application")
```

This has been working fine, up until on one of our machines we've installed a new version of PC DMIS. So we now have 2 versions of PCDLRN installed. The particular machine in question will only load the older version. All our other machines loads up the most recent version.

How does the above code decide which version to use if multiple versions exist?

I've tried uninstalling the older version and reinstalling the newer version, but I then get an error because the code is still looking for that version.

Comment: Couple things to check that possibly might help.  1) Inside the PC DMIS software there could be a setting/function to register is as a Com Server.  If so set as appropriate.  2) there could be a reference to the Com Server exe in the windows registry that isn't being updated/cleaned up with install/uninstall.  3) Inside your project, you could be referencing a specific version PC DMIS

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Registering Assemblies with COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/registering-assemblies-with-com)

Comment: Have you checked the bitness (ie: 32-bit / 64-bit) for the installed program, the OS, and your program?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the registry at key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PCDLRN.Application.xx.xx
```

In your script directly reference the version. Mine (2019 R2) is listed as `14.2`. Replace the `CreateObject("PCDLRN.Application")` in your script with `CreateObject("PCDLRN.Application.14.2")`.

This has always worked for me. Keep in mind that you'll have to do this to all your scripts every time you update. It's probably a better idea to make sure to fully uninstall old versions before installing new ones so they register properly.